# Проблема прав доступа у загруженных изображений через django admin

Tags: linux, django, ubuntu

У меня такая проблема: у модели есть поле ImageField, при загрузке гифок они сохраняются в нужной папке. Но после, у загруженных изображений нет права на чтение(rw-----), соответственно на сайте они не выводятся. Приходится вручную прописывать каждой гифке chmod 644. Собственно вопрос, можно ли сделать, чтобы по умолчанию выставлялись нужные права? ОС: ubuntu 18.04, также обычные картинки png, jpg загружаются нормально.

Comment: `umask`? https://losst.ru/komanda-umask-v-linux